# ¿Qué sería "sausage roll" en español?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, español-neutral

[Según la Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sausage_roll), *sausage roll* es un piscolabis o tentempié para llevar, muy popular en la Commonwealth. Consta de una envoltura de hojaldre con un relleno de *sausage meat* (¿carne picada?) que se hornea.

[image]

Reconozco que no soy muy aficionado a este tipo de comidas pero no creo que sea muy popular aquí en España, si existe, este producto. Menos sé si habrá alguna traducción que se entendiera en todo el mundo hispanohablante. ¿Cómo le llamaríais? ¿Hay algún equivalente exacto y conocido en vuestro país?

Comment: _Salchicha envuelta en hojaldre_ : ) En general, esto suelen ser "pastitas con relleno".

Comment: Je, je... y horneada :) Pero las pastas suelen ser dulces ¿de salchicha o carne picada?

Comment: Ese no lo he visto por aquí, pero seguro que lo hay porque por estos lados hacemos pasteles de cualquier cosa. Llamamos pasteles a la pasta hojaldrada horneada rellena de cualquier cosa dulce o salada (queso, piña, jamón, carne molida, papa, maíz, pollo, arequipe, guayaba, etc). Ese por aquí se llamaría "pastel de salchicha" o "pastel de chorizo" dependiendo del tipo de "embutido" que lleve por dentro (Salchicha es la del 'hotdog' y chorizo es el del muy conocido choripan de los Argentinos)

Comment: En varios lugares del mundo *sausage* es `longaniza` o `chorizo`. `Salchicha` se usa (en esos varios lugares del mundo) para referirse a una *vienesa* (la que utiliza en los *hot dogs*).

Comment: Y particularmente en Chile (desconozco si también en otros lados) se usa la palabra *roll* tal como en inglés. Entonces se diría como `roll de longaniza`. Esto en realidad no lo he escuchado nunca, pero se usa harto en la comida japonesa, como diciendo `comer un roll (de sushi)`.

Comment: Si son porciones pequeñas, este tipo de "snacks" suelen llamarse "saladitos", y no incluyen exclusivamente los que llevan carne picada o salchicha en su interior, sino que pueden contener mucha más variedad de elementos

Comment: Bueno "roll" se puede traducir en este caso como "rollo", asi sería algo como "Rollo de Carne"....

Comment: Veo muy interesantes sugerencias aquí en los comentarios. Supongo que el problema básico es que el _roll_ no es una comida especialmente típica en los países donde se habla el castellana, por lo que no se ha creado un término ad hoc. De todos modos, la sugerencia de @AdrianaHernández me convence bastante.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow some of the links from that Wikipedia page you eventually find one which does have a corresponding Spanish page [Pigs in blankets](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigs_in_blankets) from which I deduce that most translations involve *salchichas*, as @fedorqui suggested.

Note that pigs in blankets are only similar to sausage rolls in the US, in Britain pigs in blankets are different from sausage rolls.